# How to join a table with each group of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. Each date is Monday of each week.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' :['2020-04-20', '2020-05-11','2020-05-18',
                                 '2020-04-20', '2020-04-27','2020-05-04','2020-05-18'],
                         'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                          'count': [23, 44, 125, 6, 9, 10, 122]})

    date      name  count
0   2020-04-20  A   23
1   2020-05-11  A   44
2   2020-05-18  A   125
3   2020-04-20  B   6
4   2020-04-27  B   9
5   2020-05-04  B   10
6   2020-05-18  B   122
```

Neither 'A' and 'B' covers the whole date range. Both of them have some missing dates, which means the counts on that week is 0.  Below is all the dates:

```
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({ 'date':['2020-04-20', '2020-04-27','2020-05-04','2020-05-11','2020-05-18'] })
```

So what I need is like the dataframe below:

```
    date      name  count
0   2020-04-20  A   23
1   2020-04-27  A   0
2   2020-05-04  A   0
3   2020-05-11  A   44
4   2020-05-18  A   125
5   2020-04-20  B   6
6   2020-04-27  B   9
7   2020-05-04  B   10
8   2020-05-11  B   0
9   2020-05-18  B   122
```

It seems like I need to join (merge) `df_dates` with `df` for each name group ( A and B) and then fill the data with missing name and missing count value with 0's. Does anyone know achieve that? how I can join with another table with a grouped table?

I tried and no luck...

```
pd.merge(df_dates, df.groupby('name'), how='left', on='date')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `reindex` with multiple index creation

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_dates.date,df.name.unique()],names=['date','name'])  
s=df.set_index(['date','name']).reindex(idx,fill_value=0).reset_index().sort_values('name')
Out[136]: 
         date name  count
0  2020-04-20    A     23
2  2020-04-27    A      0
4  2020-05-04    A      0
6  2020-05-11    A     44
8  2020-05-18    A    125
1  2020-04-20    B      6
3  2020-04-27    B      9
5  2020-05-04    B     10
7  2020-05-11    B      0
9  2020-05-18    B    122
```

Or

```
s=df.pivot(*df.columns).reindex(df_dates.date).fillna(0).reset_index().melt('date')
Out[145]: 
         date name  value
0  2020-04-20    A   23.0
1  2020-04-27    A    0.0
2  2020-05-04    A    0.0
3  2020-05-11    A   44.0
4  2020-05-18    A  125.0
5  2020-04-20    B    6.0
6  2020-04-27    B    9.0
7  2020-05-04    B   10.0
8  2020-05-11    B    0.0
9  2020-05-18    B  122.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just fill in the union of dates in `df`, you can do:

```
(df.set_index(['date','name'])
   .unstack('date',fill_value=0)
   .stack().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  name        date  count
0    A  2020-04-20     23
1    A  2020-04-27      0
2    A  2020-05-04      0
3    A  2020-05-11     44
4    A  2020-05-18    125
5    B  2020-04-20      6
6    B  2020-04-27      9
7    B  2020-05-04     10
8    B  2020-05-11      0
9    B  2020-05-18    122
```